# FTP access to a windows machine on LAN?

Tags: networking, windows, nautilus, samba, shared-folders

I am on a LAN network on which most of the systems are Windows based and only I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

I want to access the Shared folders on these systems using my ubuntu.

I have installed `samba` and am able to access these folders using `Nautilus`.

However I want to be able to browse these using commandline or some other software like `FileZilla`.

Entering the IP of the host in Filezilla does not work.

How should I go about doing this?

*(Background info: The reason why I'm asking this is that a few systems on the LAN do not appear in Nautilus. I verified that they are connectible by using `ping`. On windows when such a situation occurs i.e. and a host fails to appear in the explorer, I simply press `Start + R`, type `\\host-ip` and press enter. What is the equivalent in Ubuntu?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ftp access you need to install ftp server on those windows system.

Based on your clarification, I think following is the answer to the question.

In nautilus, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

On the location bar type like

`smb://HOST_IP_ADDRESS/`

Answer (score 0):

You can install the filezilla FTP server on the windows machine or vsftpd on the linux machine. this will allow for two way communication between the different operating systems. 
vsftpd is a very good ftp server for linux and is very customizable.